# How to deploy an asp.net website in windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a asp.net website that's in asp.net 2.0. How to deploye in azure?

Answer (score 3):

You question is very vague  due to the fact that now there are three way you can deploy your ASP.NET website to Windows Azure. :

1. Windows Azure Web Sites:

   This is in preview phase and released very recently. You can create a free website by signing up to Windows Azure Preview and create upto 10 free shared websites using the information provided below:

   [Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site and SQL Database](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/)
2. Windows Azure Virtual Machine:

   In this method you create your own Virtual Machine with IIS and then deploy your ASP.NET application directly to it. The Virtual Machine is persisted so anything you will deploy to your virtual machine will persist.

   [Create a Virtual Machine Running Windows Server 2008 R2](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/tutorials/virtual-machine-from-gallery/)
3. Windows Azure Web Role

   This is the PaaS based Windows Azure Cloud service where you can deploy to your application directly to Windows Azure cloud using Windows Azure SDK as described below:

   [Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Cloud Service and SQL Database](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/)

As there is lot of information above and you might be overwhelm, I would suggest just stick with the option #1. Signup for Windows Azure Preview and create your "Windows Azure Website" and start from there.

Comment: Hi , in the second method seems you forgot the detail of the deployment of website. just include the instruction of the creation of VM. could you update it or give some helpful hypelink? thanks.